# Fabricjs pan and zoom

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How can I pan and zoom using fabricjs? I've tried using the methods zoomToPoint and setZoom but they do not work for panning. Once I start using different zoom points I start having trouble.

```
$('#zoomIn').click(function(){
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 ) ;
}) ;

$('#zoomOut').click(function(){
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1 ) ;
}) ;

$('#goRight').click(function(){
    //Need to implement
}) ;

$('#goLeft').click(function(){
    //Need to implement
}) ;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdramos/ux16013L/

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? On what do I make the adjustment?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved it using:

relativePan()
absolutePan()

[Update]

```
$('#goRight').click(function(){
    var units = 10 ;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(units,0) ;
    canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
}) ;

$('#goLeft').click(function(){
    var units = 10 ;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(-units,0) ;
    canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
}) ;
$('#goUp').click(function(){
    var units = 10 ;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(0,-units) ;
    canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
}) ;

$('#goDown').click(function(){
    var units = 10 ;
    var delta = new fabric.Point(0,units) ;
    canvas.relativePan(delta) ;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ux16013L/2/

Comment: Can you provide some example code and update your JSFiddle? Thanks!

Comment: Please im trying to do the exact same thing !

Comment: Please see udpate. This is what I have.

Comment: suppose if you zoom in and move to left or right etc and then zoom out, then you will end with some position which is not initial position!! is it possible to reset to initial position??

Comment: how to reset to actual  canvas ?

Answer (score 19):

I know it is already answered, but I had to do a mouse panning, so I adapted the fiddle of the accepted answer to do so. I post it here for anyone who has to do something like this. This is just the main idea:

```
var panning = false;
canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
    panning = false;
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
    panning = true;
});
canvas.on('mouse:move', function (e) {
    if (panning && e && e.e) {
        var units = 10;
        var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
        canvas.relativePan(delta);
    }
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gncabrera/hkee5L6d/5/

Comment: This does not seem to work in IE. From the looks of it e.e.movementX and e.e.movementY does not exist in the IE version of fabric.js. Quickly looked around and found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355425/fabricjs-is-not-giving-me-movementx-and-movementy-to-pan-a-image-in-ie-however

Comment: dear have you checked after zoom, if you can draw some shapes, like polygon , or circle using mouse ? there is mouse displacement issue after zoomin or out

Answer (score 9):

Here is my solution for canvas zoom (using mouse wheel) and pan (using left/up/right /down keys or shift key + mouse left down + mouse move).

https://jsfiddle.net/milanhlinak/7s4w0uLy/8/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc"></canvas>

    <script>
        var Direction = {
            LEFT: 0,
            UP: 1,
            RIGHT: 2,
            DOWN: 3
        };

        var zoomLevel = 0;
        var zoomLevelMin = 0;
        var zoomLevelMax = 3;

        var shiftKeyDown = false;
        var mouseDownPoint = null;

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
            width: 500,
            height: 500,
            selectionKey: 'ctrlKey'
        });

        canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            left: 100,
            top: 100,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            fill: '#faa'

        }));
        canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            left: 300,
            top: 300,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            fill: '#afa'
        }));

        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {
            var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e, true);
            mouseDownPoint = new fabric.Point(pointer.x, pointer.y);
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (options) {
            mouseDownPoint = null;
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function (options) {
            if (shiftKeyDown && mouseDownPoint) {
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e, true);
                var mouseMovePoint = new fabric.Point(pointer.x, pointer.y);
                canvas.relativePan(mouseMovePoint.subtract(mouseDownPoint));
                mouseDownPoint = mouseMovePoint;
                keepPositionInBounds(canvas);
            }
        });
        fabric.util.addListener(document.body, 'keydown', function (options) {
            if (options.repeat) {
                return;
            }
            var key = options.which || options.keyCode; // key detection
            if (key == 16) { // handle Shift key
                canvas.defaultCursor = 'move';
                canvas.selection = false;
                shiftKeyDown = true;
            } else if (key === 37) { // handle Left key
                move(Direction.LEFT);
            } else if (key === 38) { // handle Up key
                move(Direction.UP);
            } else if (key === 39) { // handle Right key
                move(Direction.RIGHT);
            } else if (key === 40) { // handle Down key
                move(Direction.DOWN);
            }
        });
        fabric.util.addListener(document.body, 'keyup', function (options) {
            var key = options.which || options.keyCode; // key detection
            if (key == 16) { // handle Shift key
                canvas.defaultCursor = 'default';
                canvas.selection = true;
                shiftKeyDown = false;
            }
        });
        jQuery('.canvas-container').on('mousewheel', function (options) {
            var delta = options.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
            if (delta != 0) {
                var pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e, true);
                var point = new fabric.Point(pointer.x, pointer.y);
                if (delta > 0) {
                    zoomIn(point);
                } else if (delta < 0) {
                    zoomOut(point);
                }
            }
        });

        function move(direction) {
            switch (direction) {
            case Direction.LEFT:
                canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(-10 * canvas.getZoom(), 0));
                break;
            case Direction.UP:
                canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(0, -10 * canvas.getZoom()));
                break;
            case Direction.RIGHT:
                canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(10 * canvas.getZoom(), 0));
                break;
            case Direction.DOWN:
                canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(0, 10 * canvas.getZoom()));
                break;
            }
            keepPositionInBounds(canvas);
        }


        function zoomIn(point) {
            if (zoomLevel < zoomLevelMax) {
                zoomLevel++;
                canvas.zoomToPoint(point, Math.pow(2, zoomLevel));
                keepPositionInBounds(canvas);
            }
        }

        function zoomOut(point) {
            if (zoomLevel > zoomLevelMin) {
                zoomLevel--;
                canvas.zoomToPoint(point, Math.pow(2, zoomLevel));
                keepPositionInBounds(canvas);
            }
        }

        function keepPositionInBounds() {
            var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
            var xMin = (2 - zoom) * canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            var xMax = zoom * canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            var yMin = (2 - zoom) * canvas.getHeight() / 2;
            var yMax = zoom * canvas.getHeight() / 2;

            var point = new fabric.Point(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2);
            var center = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, canvas.viewportTransform);

            var clampedCenterX = clamp(center.x, xMin, xMax);
            var clampedCenterY = clamp(center.y, yMin, yMax);

            var diffX = clampedCenterX - center.x;
            var diffY = clampedCenterY - center.y;

            if (diffX != 0 || diffY != 0) {
                canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(diffX, diffY));
            }
        }

        function clamp(value, min, max) {
            return Math.max(min, Math.min(value, max));
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have an example on Github using fabric.js Canvas panning and zooming: https://sabatinomasala.github.io/fabric-clipping-demo/

The code responsible for the panning behaviour is the following: https://github.com/SabatinoMasala/fabric-clipping-demo/blob/master/src/classes/Panning.js

It's a simple extension on the `fabric.Canvas.prototype`, which enables you to toggle 'drag mode' on the canvas as follows:

```
canvas.toggleDragMode(true); // Start panning
canvas.toggleDragMode(false); // Stop panning
```

Take a look at the following snippet, documentation is available throughout the code.

```js
const STATE_IDLE = 'idle';
const STATE_PANNING = 'panning';
fabric.Canvas.prototype.toggleDragMode = function(dragMode) {
  // Remember the previous X and Y coordinates for delta calculations
  let lastClientX;
  let lastClientY;
  // Keep track of the state
  let state = STATE_IDLE;
  // We're entering dragmode
  if (dragMode) {
    // Discard any active object
    this.discardActiveObject();
    // Set the cursor to 'move'
    this.defaultCursor = 'move';
    // Loop over all objects and disable events / selectable. We remember its value in a temp variable stored on each object
    this.forEachObject(function(object) {
      object.prevEvented = object.evented;
      object.prevSelectable = object.selectable;
      object.evented = false;
      object.selectable = false;
    });
    // Remove selection ability on the canvas
    this.selection = false;
    // When MouseUp fires, we set the state to idle
    this.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
      state = STATE_IDLE;
    });
    // When MouseDown fires, we set the state to panning
    this.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
      state = STATE_PANNING;
      lastClientX = e.e.clientX;
      lastClientY = e.e.clientY;
    });
    // When the mouse moves, and we're panning (mouse down), we continue
    this.on('mouse:move', (e) => {
      if (state === STATE_PANNING && e && e.e) {
        // let delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY); // No Safari support for movementX and movementY
        // For cross-browser compatibility, I had to manually keep track of the delta

        // Calculate deltas
        let deltaX = 0;
        let deltaY = 0;
        if (lastClientX) {
          deltaX = e.e.clientX - lastClientX;
        }
        if (lastClientY) {
          deltaY = e.e.clientY - lastClientY;
        }
        // Update the last X and Y values
        lastClientX = e.e.clientX;
        lastClientY = e.e.clientY;

        let delta = new fabric.Point(deltaX, deltaY);
        this.relativePan(delta);
        this.trigger('moved');
      }
    });
  } else {
    // When we exit dragmode, we restore the previous values on all objects
    this.forEachObject(function(object) {
      object.evented = (object.prevEvented !== undefined) ? object.prevEvented : object.evented;
      object.selectable = (object.prevSelectable !== undefined) ? object.prevSelectable : object.selectable;
    });
    // Reset the cursor
    this.defaultCursor = 'default';
    // Remove the event listeners
    this.off('mouse:up');
    this.off('mouse:down');
    this.off('mouse:move');
    // Restore selection ability on the canvas
    this.selection = true;
  }
};

// Create the canvas

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric')
canvas.backgroundColor = '#f1f1f1';

// Add a couple of rects

let rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(rect)

rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 200,
  left: 200,
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(rect)

// Handle dragmode change

let dragMode = false;
$('#dragmode').change(_ => {
  dragMode = !dragMode;
  canvas.toggleDragMode(dragMode);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="dragmode">
    Enable panning
    <input type="checkbox" id="dragmode" name="dragmode" />
  </label>
</div>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="fabric"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.15/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can this be modified to be used in StaticCanvas?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pan the canvas in the display, and not to change the position of the elements,
you can use [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/dudih/y0z33gym/1/embedded/result/).

The idea is to have a fixed size container with css of `overflow: hidden` that has an expended canvas inside it. the pan will move the canvas inside the container so the user will see different areas of the expended canvas every time.

Answer (score 0):

Zoom to center for button with percentage steps and limiter
with the method :

`Canvas.zoomToPoint(point: Point, value: number, skipSetCoords?: boolean): void`

```
const zoomCanvas = (cmd: "+" | "-") => {

    let: percent = Math.round(canvas.getZoom()*100) //starting zoom level in percentage

    const step = 5 // zoom step in percentage
    const max = 500 // max zoom level in percentage
    const min = 5 // min zoom level in percentage

    let zoom = 5
    if(cmd === "+" && percent <= max){
        zoom = Math.min(percent + step, max) // if command is '+' and percentage is lower than max then zoom in
    }
    else if  (cmd === "-" && percent >= min){
        zoom = Math.max(percent - step, min) // if command is '-' and percentage is greater than min then zoom out
    } else { return }

    const point = canvas.getCenterPoint() // get canvas centerPoint or any fabric.Point
    canvas.zoomToPoint(point, zoom / 100) // zoom to point
}
```

Set a custom zoom percentage with limiter

```
  const setCanvasZoomPercentage = (value: number) => {

    const center = canvas.getCenterPoint(); // get canvas centerPoint or any fabric.Point
    const max = 500; // max zoom level in percentage
    const min = 5; // min zoom level in percentage

    let zoom = value;

    if (zoom > max) v = max; // if value is greater than max
    if (zoom < min) v = min; // if value is lower than min

    canvas.zoomToPoint(center, zoom / 100);// center or any fabric.Point
  }
```

You can adapt **min**, **max** and **step**