# How to implement canvas panning with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs, panning

I have a Fabric.js canvas and I want to implement the full-canvas panning that software packages usually do with a "hand" tool. It's when you press one of the mouse buttons, then move over the canvas while holding the mouse button and the visible portion of the canvas changes accordingly.

You can see [in this video](https://youtu.be/mDvkcBlFWAM) what I want to achieve.

In order to implement this functionality I wrote the following code:

```
$(canvas.wrapperEl).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
    if (evt.button == 2) { // 2 is the right mouse button
        canvas.absolutePan({
            x: evt.clientX,
            y: evt.clientY
        });
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work. You can see [in this video](https://youtu.be/M-PG7j1YwaU) what happens.

How can I modify my code in order:

1. For panning to work like in the first video?
2. For the event handler to consume the event? It should prevent the context menu from appearing when the user presses or releases the right mouse button.

Comment: Have a look at this answer for disabling right click... http://stackoverflow.com/a/737043/4322803

Comment: Check my answer (and jsfiddle) here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42996626/2598453

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An easy way to pan a Fabric canvas in response to mouse movement is to calculate the cursor displacement between mouse events and pass it to `relativePan`.

Observe how we can use the `screenX` and `screenY` properties of the previous mouse event to calculate the relative position of the current mouse event:

```js
function startPan(event) {
  if (event.button != 2) {
    return;
  }
  var x0 = event.screenX,
      y0 = event.screenY;
  function continuePan(event) {
    var x = event.screenX,
        y = event.screenY;
    fc.relativePan({ x: x - x0, y: y - y0 });
    x0 = x;
    y0 = y;
  }
  function stopPan(event) {
    $(window).off('mousemove', continuePan);
    $(window).off('mouseup', stopPan);
  };
  $(window).mousemove(continuePan);
  $(window).mouseup(stopPan);
  $(window).contextmenu(cancelMenu);
};
function cancelMenu() {
  $(window).off('contextmenu', cancelMenu);
  return false;
}
$(canvasWrapper).mousedown(startPan);
```

We start panning on `mousedown` and continue panning on `mousemove`. On `mouseup`, we cancel the panning; we also cancel the `mouseup`-cancelling function itself.

The right-click menu, also known as the context menu, is cancelled by returning `false`. The menu-cancelling function also cancels itself. Thus, the context menu will work if you subsequently click outside the canvas wrapper.

Here is a page demonstrating this approach:

http://michaellaszlo.com/so/fabric-pan/

You will see three images on a Fabric canvas (it may take a moment or two for the images to load). You'll be able to use the standard Fabric functionality. You can left-click on the images to move them around, stretch them, and rotate them. But when you right-click within the canvas container, you pan the whole Fabric canvas with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried your approach and there is a small problem - see my update 1.

Comment: I failed to see that IE treats the `contextmenu` event differently. I've updated my code for IE. You may have to reload the demo page twice to clear the old JavaScript file from your browser cache.

Answer (score 6):

I have an example on Github using fabric.js Canvas panning: https://sabatinomasala.github.io/fabric-clipping-demo/

The code responsible for the panning behaviour is the following: https://github.com/SabatinoMasala/fabric-clipping-demo/blob/master/src/classes/Panning.js

It's a simple extension on the `fabric.Canvas.prototype`, which enables you to toggle 'drag mode' on the canvas as follows:

```
canvas.toggleDragMode(true); // Start panning
canvas.toggleDragMode(false); // Stop panning
```

Take a look at the following snippet, documentation is available throughout the code.

```js
const STATE_IDLE = 'idle';
const STATE_PANNING = 'panning';
fabric.Canvas.prototype.toggleDragMode = function(dragMode) {
  // Remember the previous X and Y coordinates for delta calculations
  let lastClientX;
  let lastClientY;
  // Keep track of the state
  let state = STATE_IDLE;
  // We're entering dragmode
  if (dragMode) {
    // Discard any active object
    this.discardActiveObject();
    // Set the cursor to 'move'
    this.defaultCursor = 'move';
    // Loop over all objects and disable events / selectable. We remember its value in a temp variable stored on each object
    this.forEachObject(function(object) {
      object.prevEvented = object.evented;
      object.prevSelectable = object.selectable;
      object.evented = false;
      object.selectable = false;
    });
    // Remove selection ability on the canvas
    this.selection = false;
    // When MouseUp fires, we set the state to idle
    this.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
      state = STATE_IDLE;
    });
    // When MouseDown fires, we set the state to panning
    this.on('mouse:down', (e) => {
      state = STATE_PANNING;
      lastClientX = e.e.clientX;
      lastClientY = e.e.clientY;
    });
    // When the mouse moves, and we're panning (mouse down), we continue
    this.on('mouse:move', (e) => {
      if (state === STATE_PANNING && e && e.e) {
        // let delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY); // No Safari support for movementX and movementY
        // For cross-browser compatibility, I had to manually keep track of the delta

        // Calculate deltas
        let deltaX = 0;
        let deltaY = 0;
        if (lastClientX) {
          deltaX = e.e.clientX - lastClientX;
        }
        if (lastClientY) {
          deltaY = e.e.clientY - lastClientY;
        }
        // Update the last X and Y values
        lastClientX = e.e.clientX;
        lastClientY = e.e.clientY;

        let delta = new fabric.Point(deltaX, deltaY);
        this.relativePan(delta);
        this.trigger('moved');
      }
    });
  } else {
    // When we exit dragmode, we restore the previous values on all objects
    this.forEachObject(function(object) {
      object.evented = (object.prevEvented !== undefined) ? object.prevEvented : object.evented;
      object.selectable = (object.prevSelectable !== undefined) ? object.prevSelectable : object.selectable;
    });
    // Reset the cursor
    this.defaultCursor = 'default';
    // Remove the event listeners
    this.off('mouse:up');
    this.off('mouse:down');
    this.off('mouse:move');
    // Restore selection ability on the canvas
    this.selection = true;
  }
};

// Create the canvas

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('fabric')
canvas.backgroundColor = '#f1f1f1';

// Add a couple of rects

let rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(rect)

rect = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  top: 200,
  left: 200,
  fill: '#f00'
});
canvas.add(rect)

// Handle dragmode change

let dragMode = false;
$('#dragmode').change(_ => {
  dragMode = !dragMode;
  canvas.toggleDragMode(dragMode);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="dragmode">
    Enable panning
    <input type="checkbox" id="dragmode" name="dragmode" />
  </label>
</div>
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="fabric"></canvas>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.15/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about FabricJS, but it could be in such a way:

1. > for it to work like in the first video:

   By making use of CSS `cursor` property, toggling it on `mousedown` and `mouseup` events using javascript.
2. > the event handler consume the event (prevent the context menu from appearing, when the user releases the right mouse button):

   Using javascript we return `false` on `contextmenu` event

**CODE:** *with a little problem* <sup>( * )</sup>

using jQuery [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8ar3ug8k/2/)

```
$('#test').on('mousedown', function(e){
    if (e.button == 2) {
        // if right-click, set cursor shape to grabbing
        $(this).css({'cursor':'grabbing'});
    }
}).on('mouseup', function(){
    // set cursor shape to default
    $(this).css({'cursor':'default'});
}).on('contextmenu', function(){ 
    //disable context menu on right click
    return false;
});
```

Using raw javascript [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6f7wg7j5/1/)

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

test.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    if (e.button == 2) {
        // if right-click, set cursor shape to grabbing
        this.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
    }
});
test.addEventListener('mouseup', function(){
    // set cursor shape to default
    this.style.cursor = 'default';
});
test.oncontextmenu = function(){ 
    //disable context menu on right click
    return false;
}
```

---

<sup>( * )</sup> **Problem:**

The above snippets works as it should but there's a cross-browser issue, if you check the above fiddles in Firefox - *or Opera* -you'll see the correct behavior, when checked in Chrome and IE11 - *didn't checked it with Edge or Safari* -  I found that Chrome and IE don't support the `grabbing` cursor shape, so in the above code snippets, change the cursor lines into this:

jQuery: `$(this).css({'cursor':'move'});` [JS Fiddle 3](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8ar3ug8k/3/)

Raw javascript: `this.style.cursor = 'move';` [JS Fiddle 4](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/6f7wg7j5/2/)

Now we have a working code but without the hand cursor. but there is the following solution:-

**SOLUTIONS:**

1. Chrome and Safari support `grab` and `grabbing` with the `-webkit-` prefix like:

   ```
   $(this).css({'cursor': '-webkit-grabbing'});
   ```

   but you need to make browser sniffing first, if Firefox then the default and standard code, if Chrome and Safari then with the `-webkit-` prefix, and this still makes IE out of the game.
2. Have a look at [*this example*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto), test it with Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and IE you can see that `cursor: url(foo.bar)` works and supported in *ALL* browsers.
   Chrome, Safari, Firefox and Opera shows the yellow smile image `smiley.gif`, but IE shows the red ball cursor `url(myBall.cur)`.

   So I think you can make use of this, and a grabbing hand image like this
   [image]

   Or this:

   [image]

   You can use an image like the above, a `png` or `gif` format with all browsers except IE which supports `.cur`, so you need to find a way to convert it into a `.cur`. Google search shows many result of [*convert image to cur*](https://www.google.iq/search?q=covert%20image%20to%20cur&oq=covert%20image%20to%20cur&aqs=chrome..69i57.7863j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=convert%20image%20to%20cur)

***Note that***, although this `cursor:url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto;` - *with fallback support separated by comma*, works well in the W3Schools example shown above, I couldn't get it to work the same way in javascript, I tried `$(this).css({'cursor': 'grabbing, move'});` but it didn't work.
  I also tried doing it as CSS class

```
.myCursor{ cursor: grabbing, -webkit-grabbing, move; }
```

Then with jQuery `$(this).addClass('myCursor');` but no avail either.

So you still need to make browser sniffing whether you are going the second solution or a hybrid fix of the both  solutions, [*this is my code*](http://pastebin.com/sHiV3zrm) which I've used couple times to detect browser and it worked well at the time of this post but you porbabely won't need the "Mobile" and "Kindle" parts.

```js
// Detecting browsers
$UA = navigator.userAgent;

if ($UA.match(/firefox/i)) {
 $browser = 'Firefox';
} else if ($UA.indexOf('Trident') != -1 && $UA.indexOf('MSIE') == -1) {
 $browser = 'MSIE';
} else if ($UA.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
 $browser = 'MSIE';
} else if ($UA.indexOf('OPR/') != -1) {
 $browser = 'Opera';
} else if ($UA.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
 $browser = 'Chrome';
} else if ($UA.indexOf("Safari")!=-1) {
 $browser = 'Safari';
}
if($UA.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Nokia|Mobile|Opera Mini/i)) {
 $browser = 'Mobile';
}else if($UA.match(/KFAPWI/i)){
 $browser = 'Kindle';
}

console.log($browser);
```

---

**Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor
- http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/
- Google images search of [grabbing hand cursor](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=667&q=grabbing%20hand%20cursor&oq=grabbing%20hand%20cursor&gs_l=img.3...967.3357.0.3697.20.6.0.14.14.0.213.614.0j1j2.3.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..9.11.643.DMKLHRKXypE)

Answer (score 1):

i have made an example on jsfiddle , that we can actually drag the whole canvas with all its objects, into a parent div, like the picture,and i will try to explain it step by step.

[image]

1. First of all i download the drag library jquery.dradscroll.js, you can find it on the net. This is a small js file that with little changes it can helps us complete the task.
   download link: http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Javascript_Free_Code/jQuery_Scroll/Download_jquery_dragscroll_Free_Java_Code.htm
2. create the container that holds our canvas.

   ```
     <div class="content">
       <canvas id="c" width="600" height="700" ></canvas>    
     </div>
   ```
3. little css

   ```
   .content{
      overflow:auto;
      width:400px;
      height:400px;
   }
   ```
4. javascript:

   a. create the canvas.

   b. make default cursor , when it is over canvas , open hand

   `canvas.defaultCursor = 'url(" http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur") 15 15, crosshair';`

   c. override the __onMouseDown function , for change to the **closedhand** cursor( at end).

   ```
        fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseDown = function(e){
     // accept only left clicks
     var isLeftClick  = 'which' in e ? e.which === 1 : e.button === 1;
     if (!isLeftClick && !fabric.isTouchSupported) {
       return;
     }


     if (this.isDrawingMode) {
       this._onMouseDownInDrawingMode(e);
       return;
     }

     // ignore if some object is being transformed at this moment
     if (this._currentTransform) {
       return;
     }

     var target = this.findTarget(e),
         pointer = this.getPointer(e, true);

     // save pointer for check in __onMouseUp event
     this._previousPointer = pointer;

     var shouldRender = this._shouldRender(target, pointer),
         shouldGroup = this._shouldGroup(e, target);

     if (this._shouldClearSelection(e, target)) {
       this._clearSelection(e, target, pointer);
     }
     else if (shouldGroup) {
       this._handleGrouping(e, target);
       target = this.getActiveGroup();
     }

     if (target && target.selectable && !shouldGroup) {
       this._beforeTransform(e, target);
       this._setupCurrentTransform(e, target);
     }
     // we must renderAll so that active image is placed on the top canvas
     shouldRender && this.renderAll();

     this.fire('mouse:down', { target: target, e: e });
     target && target.fire('mousedown', { e: e });

     if(!canvas.getActiveObject() || !canvas.getActiveGroup()){
       flag=true;
       //change cursor to closedhand.cur
       canvas.defaultCursor = 'url("http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/closedhand_8_8.cur") 15 15, crosshair';     
   }//end if
   ```
5. override the __onMouseUp event ,to change back the cursor to openhand.

   ```
      fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseUp = function(e){
          if(flag){
             canvas.defaultCursor = 'url(" http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur") 15 15, crosshair';
             flag=false;
          }
       };
   ```
6. You initialize the dragScroll() to work on the content that hosts the canvas:

   ```
       $('.content').dragScroll({});
   ```
7. **Some small changes on the jquery.dragScroll.js file, so as to understand when to drag the canvas and when not**. On mousedown() event we add an if statement to check whether we have an active object or group.If true ,no canvas drag.

   ```
      $($scrollArea).mousedown(function (e) {
       if (canvas.getActiveObject() || canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
           console.log('no drag');return;
       } else {                                             
          console.log($('body'));
           if (typeof options.limitTo == "object") {
               for (var i = 0; i < options.limitTo.length; i++) {
                   if ($(e.target).hasClass(options.limitTo[i])) {
                       doMousedown(e);
                   }
               }
           } else {
               doMousedown(e);
           }
       }
   });
   ```
8. on **mousedown** event we grab the DOM element (.content) and get the **top & left position**

   ```
     function doMousedown(e) {

           e.preventDefault();
           down = true;
           x = e.pageX;
           y = e.pageY;        
           top = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.scrollTop; // .content
           left = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.scrollLeft;// .content
       }
   ```
9. If we dont want to have the scrollbars visible:

   ```
       .content{
      overflow:hidden;
      width:400px;
      height:400px;
   ```

   }
10. There is a small problem though,jsfiddle, accepts only https libraries ,so it blocks fabricjs, except if you add it from 'https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js', but again it still blocks it some times (at least on my chrome and mozilla).

jsfiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/tornado1979/up48rxLs/

you may have better luck ,than me, on your browser , but it would definitelly work  on your live app.

Anyway, 
  i hope helps ,good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered, but I redid the pen created in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34461187/13356573) using the new version of fabricjs (4.5.0)

Pen: https://codepen.io/201flaviosilva/pen/GROLbQa

In this case, I used the middle button in the mouse to pan :)

```js
// Enable mouse middle button
canvas.fireMiddleClick = true;

// Mouse Up Event
if (e.button === 2) currentState = STATE_IDLE;

// Mouse Down Event
if (e.button === 2) currentState = STATE_PANNING;
```

:)

Comment: Unfortunately the codepen is no longer available