# What's the official way to zoom and pan the canvas in FabricJS?

Tags: fabricjs

I see for zooming and panning in Fabric JS there are the commands Canvas.setZoom, absolutePan and relativePan but can anyone show with example code how to use them, especially in using both mouse and touch events to control them?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabricjs pan and zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466322/fabricjs-pan-and-zoom)