# FabricJS is not giving me movementX and movementY to pan a image in IE, however it works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am loading a image in fabric.js and trying to add pan functionality to the image using [this link](http://www.studyjs.com/fabricjs/scale.html) .
However, it works fine in Firefox, Chrome but doesn't work in IE(it just renders the image).

Here's the code :

```
var panImg = function () {
        var panning = false;
        canvas.on('mouse:up', function (e) {
            panning = false;
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:out', function (e) {
            panning = false;
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function (e) {
            panning = true;
        });
        canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
            if (panning && e && e.e) {
                console.log(e.e.movementX);
                var delta = new fabric.Point(e.e.movementX, e.e.movementY);
                canvas.relativePan(delta);
            }
        });
    }
```

If I debug ,what I see is `e.e.movementX` gives proper values in case of FF and Chrome but it gives `undefined` in case of IE.
Is this a Fabric.js issue or am I missing something?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/movementY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the answer with the help of @Infer-on 
Code :

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
            if (panning && e && e.e) {
                var x = e.e.movementX;
                var y = e.e.movementY;
                if(!x) {
                    x = e.e.screenX - previousEvent.e.screenX;
                    y = e.e.screenY - previousEvent.e.screenY;
                }
                var delta = new fabric.Point(x, y);
                canvas.relativePan(delta);
            }
            previousEvent = e;
        });
```

Comment: But fabricjs guys must handle it , it will make their library stronger :)